# What will happen to the remaining tasks when ContinueWhenAny is invoked?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, taskfactory

What will happen to the remaining tasks when  TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny(Task[], Action(Task)) is invoked? DO the remaining tasks get cancelled or will be running in the background after a particular task is completed first? How do we cancel them if they are running in the background?

Comment: It is not even possible to cancel a `Task` in general. Only if it cooperates.

Answer (score 3):

The remaining tasks run as normal. This continuation triggers when the first `Task` completes.

Cancel the remaining tasks like this:

```
var tknSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(DoWork(tknSource.Token))); //pass the token to the tasks
}

TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny(tasks.ToArray(), p => tknSource.Cancel()); //requests a cenllation on tasks that are still running
```

Note that you can only *request* cancellation. `DoWork` has to observe and act upon the token as it changes state.

[Check out the MSDN article on Task Cancellation for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How do we cancel the remaining tasks?